# Vertica and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model, vertica

I know that Vertica has ADO.NET drivers. Has anyone tried to run Entity Framework on Vertica? If it doesn't work (expected) what might be involved in making it work. Any shared experience with this problem will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried Entity Framework with Vertica, however one piece of advice I can give you is that Vertica's connection handling is very similar to Postgresql. Very often if you can get your client-side to connect to Postgresql, it will connect to Vertica. So even if the ADO.NET drivers don't work out, using the Postgresql ones might. [Look at this blog entry](http://www.wekeroad.com/2014/02/05/using-entity-framework-6-with-postgresql/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep all this in mind. As a matter of fact I might try pg first and will go from there.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing how it turns out for you.

Comment: Well, I ended up writing EF provider services for Vertica. I look at both sql and pgsql providers, though.